# Quadratic residue of composite numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$ and $ab \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\;m)$. Prove that $b$ is also quadratic residue modulo $m$.

The above question is from Niven & Zuckerman " Introduction to the Theory of Numbers".
Actually if we consider $m$ as prime it's straightforward but how to handle this question for composite number?

Comment: Hint: Write $a = x^2$ (mod $m$), and deduce from the hypothesis that $x$ must be invertible modulo $m$.

Comment: @MayankJha Note I deleted my answer, and proposed the duplicate of [Product of Quadratic Residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654161/602049), since $1$ is a quadratic residue, so your question is basically answered as a special case of the other post.

Comment: It'd be nice if you keep the answer. Sometimes people search the specific question so they could see your answer. Anyways it's your wish

Comment: Moreover that question is answered in context of m being a prime. So not so general answer but a special case

Comment: @MayankJha Thanks for the feedback. Note I deleted my answer to avoid anybody perceiving I was also voting to close so there wouldn't be other answers to compete with mine for reputation. As for the other post, despite the answerer using $p$ for the modulus, it's not explicitly stated anywhere the modulus being prime, although I believe there is an issue with using fields with composite #'s (e.g, have to exclude not only non-zero, but any #'s not relatively prime), but the OP basically answered this in a general case, plus the first part of the accepted answer also works in general.